# Optimizing External Image Host Thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, image, performance, pagespeed, gtmetrix

We use imagebam, imagevenue, pixhost etc. to serve our blog posts thumbnails but those are slows down our website and its score by pagespeed, gtmetrix.
How to optimize those external image host thumbnails?
How to add expire headers into them?
How to leverage their browser caching?

Here is our score: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.vintagepornbay.com/lH6oi2Cc
PageSpeed Score
(43%) 
YSlow Score
(51%)

Comment: So what do you suggest for me to overcome from these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't** optimise images that you are not serving.

You can use this plugin to bring the images onto your own server.

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-external-images/

Then you can Smush to optimise the images.

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smushit/

Then use this plugin to add expires headers.

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/expire-tags/

Comment: Which one is the most optimising option?